# How can I debug into an Intel C++ library from managed code?

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, unmanaged, intel

I've got a C#/NUnit test calling into a C++ library compiled using the Intel C++ compiler (version 12, I beleive). I've got the PDB, disabled 'Just My Code', enabled Unmanaged Code Debugging. Still, ordinary debugging doesn't work - it says it hasn't got the sources and offers to show disassemly.

In addition: I'm constantly experiencing VS2010 crashing while working on this.

Just curious whether anyone has encountered this problem.

Comment: using visual studio or a different debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDB file needs to be in the same directory that the assembly is loaded out of.  NUnit copies the test dll to a temp directory and loads it from there -- did it copy the PDB.

One way to check is to use ProcMon (which can show all file accesses) and filter for PDB files to see where it's trying to load it from.  ProcMon is available for free from MS:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: No, the PDB is stored together with the other test assemblies.

Comment: 1. Install Procmon. 2. Run it and set the filter to include files that end with .pdb 3. Run NUnit in the debugger.  4. Note where PDB files are loaded from -- are they there?

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic solution. You need the source code in order to step through the code at the source-level.

You should be able to step through the assembly code, but depending on your ASM proficiency, that might not be very helpful. ;)

If you don't have access to the source code, you just have to do the best you can, debugging the code you *can* see.

Comment: Ah. Doesn't the debugger show an option to locate the PDB and source if it can't be found automatically?

Comment: The option 'Browse to find source' is disabled

Comment: This is probably because it couldn't find the PDB.